# Angular return value from one ts to another

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I have two ts files as below:

**Data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyStorage } from '../storage';

@Injectable()
export class itemFromStorage {
constructor(public storage: Storage) {  

}

    GetItemDataFromStorage(current){        
        this.storage.get(current).then((val) => {
          return val;  //????    
        }); 
   };    

}
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { itemFromStorage } from '../data'

export class item_thumb {
    constructor(public itemStorage: itemFromStorage) { 

    };  

   fetchThumbData(){
     var data = this.itemStorage.GetItemDataFromStorage(this.dataNumber);
     console.log(data);//????
   }
}
```

From the `data.ts`, how do I return the data value to `main.ts`?

Comment: Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/. It's about angular 1 promises, but the concept of standard JS promises is exactly the same.

Comment: Style note: classes in TypeScript use UpperCamelCase and methods use lowerCamelCase, so your classes should be `ItemFromStorage` and `ItemThumb` and your method should be `getItemDataFromStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data.ts method should return only the request itself, without subscribing to it:

```
    GetItemDataFromStorage(current){        
        return this.storage.get(current);
   };
```

and in your main.ts method subscribe and receive the data:

```
   fetchThumbData(){
     var data = this.itemStorage.GetItemDataFromStorage(this.dataNumber).then((data) => {
          console.log(data);//???? 
        }); 

   }
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly :) also [hightlighting hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) can make it much easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your Data.ts is returning a promise.
**Main.ts**

```
export class item_thumb {
    constructor(public itemStorage: itemFromStorage) { 
    };  
   fetchThumbData(){
     let promise = this.itemStorage.GetItemDataFromStorage(this.dataNumber);
     promise.then(data => console.log(data));     
   }
}
```

To get the value synchronously: [Get the value of a Javascript Promise in a synchronous way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220554/get-the-value-of-a-javascript-promise-in-a-synchronous-way)